# Paginate Category list wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, categories

How to put this category list in a pagination because currently I have a code that show all the list of category including post by category.
The problem is how to make it paginate if the category list exceed by 10.

```
 $cats = get_categories("exclude=1,5,15"); 

            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                    // setup the cateogory ID
                        $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
                        $cat_child =$cat -> category_parent;

                    // Make a header for the cateogry
                        echo "<div class='anchor2' id='cat_".$cat_id. "'></div>";
                        echo "<div id='". $cat_child ."'class='cat_id".$cat_id." cat-cont large-6 medium-6 columns pad25px'>";
                        echo "<h5 class='title-post cat_id_" . $cat_id ."' >".$cat->name."</h5>";
                        echo "<a href='dev/all/#cat_".$cat_id."' class='see-more' target='_blank'>See more >></a>";

                        // create a custom wordpress query
                        query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=5&depth=1");

                        // start the wordpress loop!
                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>

                            <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'archive-grid' ); ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php else : ?>             
                                <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' ); ?>
                        <?php  endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>

            <?php echo "</div>";}// done the foreach statement ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for answer: Here is how to paginate the category list if you are showing all categories in a page.

```
   if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('page');
                    } else {$paged = 1;}

             $per_page = 4;
             $paged_offset = ($paged - 1) * $per_page;
             $paginate = array(
                            'orderby'           => 'name',
                            'order'             => 'ASC',
                            'hide_empty'        => 0,
                            'number'            => $per_page,
                            'paged'             => $paged,
                            'exclude'           => array(1,5,15,18),
                            'offset'            => $paged_offset
                        );  
            // get all the categories from the database
             $cats = get_categories($paginate);
             echo '<div class="page1">';
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                        // setup the cateogory ID

                        $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
                        $cat_child =$cat -> category_parent;


                        // Make a header for the cateogry
                        echo "<div class='anchor2' id='cat_".$cat_id. "'></div>";
                        echo "<div id='". $cat_child ."'class='cat_id".$cat_id." cat-cont large-6 medium-6 columns pad25px'>";
                        echo "<h5 class='title-post cat_id_" . $cat_id ."' >".$cat->name."</h5>";
                        echo "<a href='dev/all/#cat_".$cat_id."' class='see-more' target='_blank'>See more >></a>";
                     //   echo "<h2 id='". $cat_child ."'class='title-post cat_id_" . $cat_child ."' >".$cat->name."</h2>";
                        // create a custom wordpress query




                $args = array(
                    'cat' => $cat_id,
                    'posts_per_page' => 5,

                );

                query_posts($args);

                    query_posts($args);

                        // start the wordpress loop!
                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>

                            <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'archive-grid' ); ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php else : ?>             
                                <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' ); ?>
                        <?php  endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>


            <?php echo "</div>"; }// done the foreach statement 



            ?>
             <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
             <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using $paged variable at all in your query. Replace your code section

```
// create a custom wordpress query
query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=5&depth=1");
```

with

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {$paged = 1;}

$args = array(
'cat' => $cat_id,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged' => $paged
);

query_posts($args);
```

And it will work fine for you, additionally also you can use

```
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

For even full control, if Next and Previous buttons work, then you can comment this part and can use your code for pagination as you want to show your page numbers etc (if you don't want to use next and prev buttons etc)

Comment: yes, it's show the "more" link and change to page2 but the content doesn't change also how to set count of categories perpage? thank you

Comment: are you taken to page2 in address bar ? And is your next posts are not shown ? You are setting 'posts_per_page' to 5 which means 5 posts on each page.

Comment: yes, it takes me to page2 but it shows the same content. That 'posts_per_page' is for category post look at this one http://imgur.com/mXtZXlV the current look right now. I want to paginate those category list. Thank you hope you can help me

Comment: yes it's working right now but the one that is changing is the content of each categories not the category list. Thanks I'm struggling with this for a long time hope you can help me

Comment: can you clarify your last comment a bit, so that I can provide that solution as well if I could

Comment: the one that changing when I click more is the inner content of categories the one in the box. Not the list of categories. What I want to happen is when I click more all of the current content of the list will be change with a new one. for example in the image I send earlier it has 10 category list with 5 post in each. when I click more all of them will be change with a next list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110813/discussion-between-laraib-and-winresh24).